# Remove or Hide horizontal axis python-pptx

Tags: python-pptx

is it possible to remove vertical axis, but only the line, kepping the labels?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQK6b.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Set the width of the axis line to zero:

```
value_axis = chart.value_axis
value_axis.format.line.width = 0
```

Comment: not work :(

Anyway it help me to find other solution, I changed the line color 
category_axis.format.line.color.rgb = RGBColor(255, 255, 255)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't remove the line, but makes it white, so you don't see it anymore:

```
from pptx.dml.color import RGBColor
category_axis.format.line.color.rgb = RGBColor(255, 255, 255)
```